# Axios GET request to PHP API not working with custom header

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, cors

I'm working on a new VueJS app which accesses a simple API endpoint built in PHP via axios. I've stripped back the PHP endpoint code to a simple echo to rule out other code causing issues:

```php
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Api-Token");

echo 'hello';
```

Currently, the development is running on local development hostnames:

- vueJS app - http://app.livechat.local:8000/
- PHP API - http://api.livechat.local/

In my app, i'm doing a simple interceptor to append a custom header of 'X-Api-Token' which I will eventually validate on the endpoint.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuetify from "./vuetify";
import axios from "axios";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import App from './App.vue';
import VueSocketIOExt from "vue-socket.io-extended";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import routes from "./routes";
import './style.scss';



const socket = io(SOCKET_URL);

// axios config
axios.defaults.baseURL = API_URL;

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers = {
        'X-Api-Token': 'test'
    };
    return config;
});



Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket, vuetify, axios);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({routes});
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;


Notification.requestPermission();


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    console.log(to.name);
    if(to.name !== 'login' && to.name !== 'register' && to.name !== 'logout' && to.name !== 'forgot-password') {
        axios.get('/',{
            params: {
                endpoint: 'agentCheckSession'
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});





new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    vuetify,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

However, the moment I add the custom header, CORS responds with:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://api.livechat.local/?endpoint=agentCheckSession' from origin
> 'http://app.livechat.local:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

If I remove the custom header from the axios interceptor, it proceeds without a problem.

I've confirmed that the PHP script is valid by accessing it in the browser.

Here is the Dev Tools inspection:

[image]

How can I pass a custom header successfully? I'm looking for a valid way to resolve this in PHP and/or JS, so i'm not looking for proxy or 'disable in chrome' solutions.

Comment: What I have discovered is 'simple requests' don't allow custom headers...which is strange as I can send custom headers using jQuery's Ajax(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this part:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers = {
        'X-Api-Token': 'test'
    };
    return config;
});
```

you are overriding all the headers of the request. Try to add your header to the headers instead of override them, eg:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers.token = "test";
    return config;
});
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work either. I've also made sure to reflect the 'token' name on the backbend, still the same issue.